# Stopping too soon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, computational-physics, simulations, software

I have an object going $1000\frac ms$, $vi$, that I want to slow down to $250 \frac ms$, $vf$. I want it to slow down in $10000m$, $d$.

I want to know how much deceleration is necessary, and how long it will take.

Given the above, I have found $t = \frac{2d}{vi + vf}$. And now, given I have $vi$ and $d$ already, I can find $a$ with $t$, $d$, and $vi$. $a=\frac{2(d - (t * vi))}{t^2}$.

These all seem to work out.

$$t = 16s = \frac{2*10000}{1000\frac ms + 250\frac ms}$$
$$a = -46.875\frac {m}{s^2} =\frac{2(10000m - (16s * 1000\frac ms))}{16s^2}$$

A quick check: $v = -750\frac ms = 16s * -46.875\frac {m}{s^2}$

Since my delta is, indeed, 750, this looks "ok".

So, I try to apply it. I have a simple Java program.

```
package pkg;

public class Decel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x = -10000;
        double d = 0 - x;
        double vi = 1000;
        double vf = 250;
        double t = (2 * d) / (vi + vf);
        double a = (2 * (d - (t * vi))) / (t * t);

        System.out.println(" d=" + d + " - a=" + a + " - t=" + t + " - final v=" + a * t);

        double dt = 1;
        double totalTime = 0;
        double acc = a * dt;
        while (totalTime <= t+1) {
            System.out.println(totalTime + " x = " + x + " v " + vi);
            vi = vi + acc;
            x = x + vi * dt;
            totalTime = totalTime + dt;
        }
    }
}
```

And it displays:

```
d=10000.0 - a=-46.875 - t=16.0 - final v=-750.0
0.0 x = -10000.0 v 1000.0
1.0 x = -9046.875 v 953.125
2.0 x = -8140.625 v 906.25
3.0 x = -7281.25 v 859.375
4.0 x = -6468.75 v 812.5
5.0 x = -5703.125 v 765.625
6.0 x = -4984.375 v 718.75
7.0 x = -4312.5 v 671.875
8.0 x = -3687.5 v 625.0
9.0 x = -3109.375 v 578.125
10.0 x = -2578.125 v 531.25
11.0 x = -2093.75 v 484.375
12.0 x = -1656.25 v 437.5
13.0 x = -1265.625 v 390.625
14.0 x = -921.875 v 343.75
15.0 x = -625.0 v 296.875
16.0 x = -375.0 v 250.0
17.0 x = -171.875 v 203.125
```

The key point here is this line: `16.0 x = -375.0 v 250.0`

I'm at the 16s mark, I'm going $250\frac ms$, but I'm 375 meters too early.

Why is that?

Addenda to clarify from the answer:

I changed the code section to this:

```
double ovi = vi;
vi = vi + acc;
x = x + ((ovi + vi) / 2) * dt;
```

And it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the line of code

x = x + vi * dt;

where you have treated the velocity at one end of the interval as the constant velocity over the entire interval. You need to work out the average velocity over the time step and use that.

Comment: I changed it to this: double ovi = vi; vi = vi + acc; x = x + ((ovi + vi) / 2) * dt; and it worked, it's a bullseye. 16.0 x = 0.0 v 250.0. Thanks!